# How do I use streaming with WCF services returning a large data set?

Tags: wcf, streaming, large-data

I'm fairly new to WCF and I'm trying to figure out how streaming works.I basically have a web service that is supposed to return some information from a db.The data returned is potentially very large.I was wondering if anyone could point out a good example of how is this done.If I'm understanding things correctly, my web service method should be returning a stream object.But how do I actually pass data to the stream? Is it just a matter of serializing each object and writing it to the stream? If so, how exactly would the serializaition be done? Once again, a simple example would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just set the Binding's [TransferMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx) property to the Streamed value and work with your WCF services as you would do.  The WCF infrastructure will do all the job automatically.

Here is one more useful link:

[Streaming Message Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx)

Comment: So, I don't need to return a Stream object ??? If my web service is returning a large List for example, would this still work?

Comment: There is no need to return the stream.  It will work with large lists as well.  I've also added a new link to my answer.

Comment: Note that chaning the Binding's TransferMode to streamed give limitations on the interface of the service. It is probably a good idea to put the streamed methods in an own interface and keep the rest of the methods in an interface that remains buffered (which is the default).

Comment: Yes, there are some limitations on using the streamed transfer mode.  The last link in my answer lists them.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the part I've been missing. I keep getting a CommunicationException that states that the connection has closed unexpectedly. Could this be due to the maximum message size?

Comment: Can you debug this exception and check the exception's InnerException?  This usually contains some useful information.  Also, the maximum message size is also possible to increase.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'd revist the architecture, as returning large resultsets from any service (WCF, ASMX, etc) is an architecture smell.

There are very few acceptable reasons to return large resultsets from a service.  A combination of more/better filtering and implementing pagine are the solution.  If you are just putting a simple service veneer over your database, look into WCF Data Services, as filtering and paging are built right into the framework.  Otherwise, look into WCF Data Services to see what they are doing and mimic in your service.